# Which User Agent use Google PageSpeed?

Tags: user-agent, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Actually google page speed insights are not using these user agents

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/27.0.1453 Mobile Safari/537.36

FOR DESKTOP

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/27.0.1453 Safari/537.36

but how can i get the new user agents used by these service?

Answer (score 3):

Looking deeper into the logs of my server and printing the http header user-agent i found the User Agent from Google Page Speed Insight are the below two instances

```
{   "pattern": "Chrome-Lighthouse",
    "instances": [
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse",
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse"
    ]}
```

i'm using these object to validate with a regex if the user agent is a bot

```
regex = RegExp("Chrome-Lighthouse","ig")
regex.test("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse")
```